# How to stop if-function from executing once it's been executed in Processing?

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, collision-detection, processing

I have an if function that executes every time 2 objects overlap each other and the result being that the HP should ONLY decrease by 1, however the value of the HP keeps decreasing for as long as they are overlapping so it would go from 3 straight to 0.

```
int HP = 3;

void collision ()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) 
  {
    if (dist(balls[i].bx,balls[i].by,X,Y)< 15)
    {
      HP-=1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: processing programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int HP = 3;

void collision ()
{
   bool check = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) 
   {
      if ((dist(balls[i].bx,balls[i].by,X,Y)< 15) && check == false)
      {
         HP-=1;
         check = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Alternative:

```
int HP = 3;

void collision ()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) 
   {
      if ((dist(balls[i].bx,balls[i].by,X,Y)< 15))
      {
         HP-=1;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Alternative

Only once for each time it loops:

```
int HP = 3;

void collision () {
   int temp = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
      if ((dist(balls[i].bx,balls[i].by,X,Y)< 15)) {
         temp += 1;
      }
   }
   if (temp > 0) {
      HP = HP - 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: The first one works to an extent, if I reference "boolean check=false;" at the top of my code and not inside of void collision(). But the if function doesnt execute every time the objects overlap, it executes once.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want the if-statement to work only once in the entire loop right? Or do you mean it should only work once for each time you loop ?

Comment: Only once for each time it loops.

Comment: Or better yet if there was a delay on the execution of the if statement, so that there is time for another collision between objects to occur. Thanks for helping me out on this btw. This has been bothering me for forever.

Comment: Try the last alternative, it allows you to set the maximum (HP -= max)